# I can't find ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc in C:/Users/<user>/.ssh folder

Tags: git, github

I'm new to GitHub and I'm trying to set up my SSH keys by following the steps in https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#auto-launching-ssh-agent-on-git-for-windows to auto-start ssh-agent in Windows.

But I'm already stuck in the first step "You can run `ssh-agent` automatically when you open bash or Git shell. Copy the following lines and paste them into your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` file in Git shell" because my .ssh folder only has the ff files:

- id_ed25519
- id_ed25519.pub
- known_hosts
- known_hosts.old

I tried to look for similar files outside of my C:/Users/<user>/.ssh folder, and I found these:

- .bash_history
- .gitconfig

Is that correct? Or should I create the .profile or .bashrc file by myself? I'm new to this, so any extra explanations would be really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: If you use VSCode for coding, you can just install git and VSCode and authenticate to github Using VSCode. it is simplest and easiest method.

Comment: When you use bash, `~` is a shortcut for "your home directory". You should look for your `.bashrc` file in `C:/Users/<user>/`, not under `.ssh/`. Create it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a programming or software development question. Questions like this should generally be posted on one of the system administration sites, like https://superuser.com/, https://unix.stackexchange.com/, https://serverfault.com/, etc. On this site it will likely be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @Hujaakbar Yes, I'm using VSCode. The tutorial I'm watching (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGOj5yH7evk) says to use steps from GitHub. Do I just need to download GitHub extension in VSCode?

Comment: @LeGEC I didn't find it in `C:/Users/<user>`, but I found one in `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\bash.bashrc`. Is it the same? Or should I create one in `C:/Users/<user>`?

Comment: @Brian61354270 Sorry, I thought that since GitHub is used for source code control, it's ok to ask questions like this here. I'll check the other sites you mentioned. Thank you!

Comment: create one in your home directory